# How to emulate a multi-sig transaction?

Tags: wallet, plutus

I'm working on a Plutus contract that requires multiple signatures to unlock. To do so, I've been referencing the [MultiSig.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/MultiSig.hs) sample contract. Now, I'm looking to create traces for testing purposes, however, these tests are commented out in [Spec.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-use-cases/test/Spec.hs) with the comment "disable temporarily, because we need to adopt the signing API," but I'm not really sure what this means.

Is it currently possible to sign a transaction with multiple Wallets or PubKeyHash's? If so, how?

Comment: People complain about banks, but I can open up a joint account at a bank. I can't do that with any Cardano wallet. I'm glad you're working on this. If you receive any responses to your question, I'll be interested in seeing them. Have you put your idea(s) out on Catalyst?

Comment: Hello Richard, welcome to this community. While your contribution is valued, it might be more suitable as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Hello Richard, I am in agreement with Matthias and will do the conversion.  Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 2):

These would be witnesses on the transaction itself. The script states I need these hashes signed on the transaction and the transaction either has those witnesses and the script passes or it doesn't and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link quite useful for multi-sign scenario. https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#multi-signature-scripts

I wonder if anyone has tested the MultiSign.hs on testnet/mainnet yet? It seems the "txSignedBy" is not working as I got my fund locked.

Comment: yes, there's at least a few of these on mainnet. On testnet, I personally along with 4-5 SPOs tested multisig after allegra hard fork back in December of last year. Note that multisig via simple scripts is *not* a plutus script, so is probably not exactly what the OP is asking about.